# Changing the class of href via php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a menu with 5 different hrefs.

Each href refers to the same page but a different ID:

```
<a href="Planning.php?id=1" id="MenuButton1" class="MenuButton">Line 1</a>
<a href="Planning.php?id=2" id="MenuButton2" class="MenuButton">Line 2</a>
<a href="Planning.php?id=3" id="MenuButton3" class="MenuButton">Line 3</a>
<a href="Planning.php?id=4" id="MenuButton4" class="MenuButton">Line 4</a>
<a href="Planning.php?id=5" id="MenuButton5" class="MenuButton">Line 5</a>
```

Now I want something in my code that changes the class(for css purposes) of a `href` when I got a certain ID. Something like a selected href.

Is it possible to change my class via php or javascript?

For instance:

```
if($_GET['id'] == 1)
{
     MenuButton1.class= "SelectedLink";
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can have php output different html based on $_GET. and yes, you can have JS parse query parameters and fiddle with the DOM based on what it finds. Which you use is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $_GET['id'] is equal to $i,use class SelectedLink instead of MenuButton.

```
<?
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
    ?>
    <a href="Planning.php?id=<?=$i+1?>" id="MenuButton<?=$i+1?>" class="<?=$i!=($_GET['id']-1)?'MenuButton':'SelectedLink'?>">Line <?=$i+1?></a>
    <?
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for pushing me in the right direction :) I added an if statement to check if the `GET` value is equal to `$i`. if it is thats the selectedLink

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. Code only answers, while they may work, are not considered by many to be good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just assigning a class you could do the following:

```
<a href="Planning.php?id=1" id="MenuButton1" class="MenuButton<?= (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == 1) ? ' SelectedLink' : ''; ?>">Menu Item 1</a>
```

That way, class `SelectedLink` will only be assigned if `$_GET['id']` is `.

#### Edit

You could also build your complete menu using PHP like this:

```
// Create an array containing your menu items
$menuItems = array(
    '1' => 'Line 1',
    '2' => 'Line 1',
    '3' => 'Line 1',
    '4' => 'Line 1',
    '5' => 'Line 1',
);
<!-- Loop through the array and write your menu items -->
<?php foreach ($menuItems as $item => $name): ?>
    <a href="Planning.php?id=<?= $item; ?>" id="MenuButton<?= $item; ?>" class="MenuButton<?= (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == $item) ? ' SelectedButton' : ''; ?>">Menu Item <?= $name; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The above foreach will write your menu items. As said before, in the class I have used an shorthand if statement. This will check if the current looping menu item matches your `$_GET` parameter. If so, it will write an extra class.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the css class description based on the element tagname, and attributes using or not regular expressions depending what you want to do.
For example:

```
.MenuButton { color: black; }
.MenuButton[id=MenuButton2] { color: red; }
.MenuButton[href$='1'] { color: green; } /* all ending with 1 - ie. 1 11 111 */
.MenuButton[href$='=1'] { color: blue; } { color: blue; } /* just =1 */
```